# Getting Amp Validation errors when pasting straight from example

Tags: amp-html

I am attempting to make a new mobile version of my website using Google's Amp.  On the official website they list examples of its use.  I've copied and pasted the code from [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/basic_markup) and [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-sidebar) to create:

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
<title>Hello, AMPs</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
    "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
    "image": [
      "logo.jpg"
    ]
  }
</script>
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 
1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-
ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-
start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-
start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-
start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-
start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-
start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-
start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style 
amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-
animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
 </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
<!--     <button class="hamburger" on='tap:sidebar1.toggle'></button> -->
    <amp-sidebar id='sidebar1' layout='nodisplay'>
      <ul>
        <li> Nav item 1</li>
        <li> Nav item 2</li>
        <li> Nav item 3</li>
        <li> Nav item 4</li>
        <li> Nav item 5</li>
        <li> Nav item 6</li>
        <li> Nav item 7</li>
        <li> Nav item 8</li>
        <li> Nav item 9</li>
        <li on="tap:sidebar1.close"> Close</li>
      </ul>
    </amp-sidebar>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the console I get the validation error "The attribute 'role' in tag 'li' is missing or incorrect, but required by attribute 'on'." and "The attribute 'tabindex' in tag 'li' is missing or incorrect, but required by attribute 'on'."

This is taken straight from the example, unmodified.  It doesn't matter if i comment out or remove the toggle button.  I have a more elaborate example as well that also has validation errors.  The line of the error points to the last li element that closes the sidebar on tap.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an AMP validator or are you getting that from the HTML validator?

Comment: Amp pages attempt validation when #development=1 is appended to the end of the URL.  The output of the validator can be seen under the console of web developer tools in google chrome.

Answer (score 11):

If you put `on` attributes on elements that aren't normally clickable (like `a` or `button` elements) you need to put an [aria role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) like `role=button` on that element for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 5):

AMP forces you to apply the minimum of web accessibility. AMP forces you to add `aria role` and `tabindex` when use `on` attributes on non-clickable elements.

**What is ARIA?**

> The Web Accessibility Initiative's Accessible Rich Internet
>   Applications specification (WAI-ARIA, or just ARIA) is good for
>   bridging areas with accessibility issues that can't be managed with
>   native HTML. It works by allowing you to specify attributes that
>   modify the way an element is translated into the accessibility tree.

[More detail about ARIA.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria)

Most of the time you have to add `tabindex="0"` and `role="button"` (especially when use `on="tap:action"`):

```
<div on="tap:AMP.setState({ visible: false})" tabindex="0" role="button">...
```